# A client error (SignatureDoesNotMatch) occurred when calling the UploadServerCertificate operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-iam

Trying to install a multi-domain ssl certificate through AWSCLI using OpenSSL, it's a Comodo PositiveSSL Multidomain certificate.

I followed all the instructions on aws tutorials, and the web. I spent about 2 hours with Comodo tech support making sure I have proper files etc, re-issuing certs, etc., and still no luck.

I keep getting this error when I try to upload using the command shown [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ManagingServerCerts.html#UploadSignedCert) and [here](https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/blog/setting-up-ssl-on-aws-cloudfront-and-s3/) and there isn't much info on this error online.

`A client error (SignatureDoesNotMatch) occurred when calling the UploadServerCertificate operation: Signature not yet current: 20150704T040234Z is still later than 20150704T032257Z (20150704T030757Z + 15 min.)`

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Your system clock is wrong.

Comment: My windows clock is accurate. What do you mean by system clock and how would I fix it?

Comment: The clock on whatever computer you are using to actually run those commands, whether it's your local machine, or a remote server that you are logged into, is either substantially wrong or has its time zone setting incorrect, or both.  It appears to be about 55 minutes off.

Comment: This is a response I am getting from Aws Console when I try to upload my SSL certificate. So you're saying Amazon's sys clock is off or my local pc's? I will try uploading from another pc and see if it helps

Comment: This error points to your clock being off.  It's *possible* that the problem could be on Amazon's side, but it seems very unlikely that such an error would occur, and if it occurred, that it would go undetected.  Again, both your clock *and* your time zone selection in control panel need to be accurate.  This error suggests one or both could be wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do a

```
sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
```

Comment: -s is silencing errors. May hide some problems, as I had myself

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to pull details of RIs and Autoscaling from my AWS account using Boto3 and it was giving me the below error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the DescribeAutoScalingGroups operation: Signature not yet current: 20170206T130536Z is still later than 20170206T130524Z (20170206T130024Z + 5 min.)
```

My instance time was not correct and due to this is is giving me an error.
Running below command fixed it:

```
    root@ip-x-x-x-x:~# sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
```

Answer (score 0):

Legit answer, check if your Computer time is correct. It will solve the problem.